# Entity framework is trying to find a deleted foreign key on database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have an entity that had a foreign key with it's navigation property, but I deleted this foreign key from database and my model to create another one. Now, entity framework gives me an error, saying that the old column is missing on my model.

This is my model:

```
public class CompraVenda
{

        public CompraVenda()
        {
            this.Produtos = new HashSet<CompraVendaProdutoGrade>();
        }

        public long ID_CompraVenda { get; set; }
        public long? ID_CondicaoPagamento { get; set; }
        public long? ID_Fornecedor { get; set; }
        public long? ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public long? ID_Funcionario { get; set; }
        public long? ID_Pedido { get; set; }

        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataConfirmacao { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Observacoes { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorDesconto { get; set; }
        public decimal AcrescimoTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorFrete { get; set; }
        public int TipoDesconto { get; set; }
        public int NumeroProdutos { get; set; }

        public virtual CondicaoPagamento CondicaoPagamento { get; set; }
        public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
        public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompraVendaProdutoGrade> Produtos { get; set;     }
}
```

This is the mapping class:

```
public class CompraVendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CompraVenda>
{
        public CompraVendaMap()
        {

            this.ToTable("compravenda", "wildesk");

            this.HasKey(t => t.ID_CompraVenda);

            this.Property(t => t.ID_CompraVenda).HasColumnName("ID_CompraVenda");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_Fornecedor).HasColumnName("ID_Fornecedor");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_Cliente).HasColumnName("ID_Cliente");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_Funcionario).HasColumnName("ID_Funcionario");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_Pedido).HasColumnName("ID_Pedido");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_CondicaoPagamento).HasColumnName("ID_CondicaoPagamento");
            this.Property(t => t.Codigo).HasColumnName("Codigo");
            this.Property(t => t.Tipo).HasColumnName("Tipo");
            this.Property(t => t.DataCadastro).HasColumnName("DataCadastro");
            this.Property(t => t.DataConfirmacao).HasColumnName("DataConfirmacao");
            this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
            this.Property(t => t.Observacoes).HasColumnName("Observacoes");
            this.Property(t => t.ValorTotal).HasColumnName("ValorTotal");
            this.Property(t => t.ValorDesconto).HasColumnName("ValorDesconto");
            this.Property(t => t.AcrescimoTotal).HasColumnName("AcrescimoTotal");
            this.Property(t => t.ValorFrete).HasColumnName("ValorFrete");
            this.Property(t => t.TipoDesconto).HasColumnName("TipoDesconto");
            this.Property(t => t.NumeroProdutos).HasColumnName("NumeroProdutos");

            this.HasOptional(t => t.CondicaoPagamento).WithMany(t => t.ComprasVendas).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_CondicaoPagamento);
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Fornecedor).WithMany(t => t.ComprasVendas).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_Fornecedor);
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Cliente).WithMany(t => t.ComprasVendas).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_Cliente);
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Funcionario).WithMany(t => t.ComprasVendas).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_Funcionario);
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Pedido).WithMany(t => t.ComprasVendas).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_Pedido);

            this.HasMany(t => t.Produtos).WithRequired(t => t.CompraVenda).HasForeignKey(t => t.ID_CompraVenda);
        }
}
```

Error:

> Unknown column 'Extent1.FormaPagamento_ID_FormaPagamento' in 'field
>   list'

I already cleaned my solution, recreated my database, nothing works.

One think that I have noticed is: If I comment one of the current properties that are foreign key, EF gaves me the same error for the commented property.

Does EF read the entity schema to find foreign keys on database? Or, it makes cache of model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I'll post here for who maybe has the same problem:

I forgot to remove the old collection on `FormaPagamento` that references to `compravenda`, the collection was not mapped but was setted as virtual, so, EF was trying to find one property equivalent on `compravenda`.

My old `FormaPagamento` model code:

```
public class FormaPagamento
{

        public FormaPagamento()
        {
            this.ContasPagarReceber = new HashSet<ContaPagarReceber>();
            this.Movimentacoes = new HashSet<ContaPagarReceberMovimentacao>();
            this.ComprasVendas = new HashSet<CompraVenda>();
            this.CondicoesPagamento = new HashSet<CondicaoPagamentoFormaPagamento>();
        }

        public long ID_FormaPagamento { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public bool IsAtivo { get; set; }
        public bool IsSystem { get; set; }
        public int? Enum { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ContaPagarReceber> ContasPagarReceber { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContaPagarReceberMovimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }

        // When I removed this collection, it works.
        public virtual ICollection<CompraVenda> ComprasVendas { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CondicaoPagamentoFormaPagamento> CondicoesPagamento { get; set; }

}
```